# Programmatically adding metatags to Masterpages in Web Forms and MVC

Tags: seo, metadata, model-view-controller

Has anyone got any ideas on where we should be adding our SEO metadata in a Web Forms project? Why I ask is that currently I have two main Masterpages, one is the home page and the other one is every other page, they both have the same metadata  that’s just a generic description and set of key words about my site. The problem with that is search engines are only picking up my home page and my own search engine displays the same title and description for all results.

The other problem is the site is predominantly dynamic so if you type in a search for beach which is a major categories on the site you get 10000 results that all go to different information but all look like a link to the same page to the user.

---

**edit**

It's live here www.themorningtonpeninsula.com

Comment: Is the site live? If so, can you give us a URL? Then we can provide some specific advice based on the current state of the site. Otherwise any advice will be very general, and thus less likely to be helpful...

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why this post was moved here either, I put it up on stackoverflow.com. I didn't know about this site but I'm glad I do now!

It is in its essence a programming question and the answer is to use dynamic meta tags to your pages and your the master pages. If you do a search on this most of what comes up is "How to add meta tags to your masterpages" that's easy but not a good idea!

Put this in the page_load of you page then populate the hard coded bits from the database.

```
    Page.Header.Title = "Some new dynamically created page Title!";
    Page.Header.Description = "Some dynamically created description";
    Page.Header.Keywords = "stuff, more stuff, even more stuff";

    HtmlMeta myMetaTag = new HtmlMeta();
    myMetaTag.Name = "robots";
    myMetaTag.Content = "noindex";

    Page.Header.Controls.Add(myMetaTag);
```

Does the trick.

Cheers,

Mike.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this got migrated here since it's really a programming question. To answer the SEO aspect: yes, all pages should have unique titles that describe the page, and usually a relevant meta description.

Note, search engines *are* picking up all your pages, as a search for `site:www.themorningtonpeninsula.com` will show you. But since they all have the same title they are probably not appearing in normal searches.

For the technical side, you can definitely set the page title when using master pages in ASP. I think you can set the title when you create a new page, but if not the first line of each page should have the title attribute like in this code from one of my projects. Here the title would be "Help pages":

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" CodeFile="Help.aspx.vb" Inherits="Help" title="Help pages" %>
```

I'm not 100% sure about the meta description but it should be possible to set that in the VB/C# code behind the page. If you can't get it working I'd recommend asking a more specific programming question on Stack Overflow.